# How to feed IER (individual email result) with Tracking Triggered Send information (triggered send via API from external app)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, triggered-send, sales-cloud

i hope someone can help me with this problem here:

i've to feed the IER "**et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c**" object in **SalesCloud** from **Tracking data of Triggered Send**.

Normally with the connector it works automatically from a normal send between **SC** and **Marketing Cloud**, but in this case the triggered sent is done by an external app via API so it doesn't feed the "et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c" object with these informations.

**Is there a way to use all these informations and insert them into the IER object for each subscriber?**
Otherwise can i export the information needed into a DE and insert them with SSJS?

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image: Schema of connections]

Comment: Upvote for visualization

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question, even though it's almost three years old, because the answer might be useful for those who have the same question in the future.

Place the sendable Data Extension (Triggered Send) in the Salesforce Data Extension folder.