# IER's in SalesCloud - Historical Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

Working through getting MCC established in Sales Cloud and hitting a few roadblocks. Let's say I did not apply IER's to a contact/lead page layout in implementation of MCC, but I followed all the standard procedures when it comes to sending emails out of Marketing Cloud to be able to sync that data to SalesCloud i.e. sending from JB or Salesforce Sends and selecting "Send to Sales Cloud."

If I decided to implement those page layouts/related lists down the line to see IER's, would they theoretically be able to pull the historical send data assuming everything went as expected? Or will it only start pulling results from when its applied to the lead/contact page layout?

Thanks!

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332105/how-to-feed-ier-individual-email-result-with-tracking-triggered-send-informati